# Is Ubuntu 12.04 compatible with the Intel 845G motherboard chipset?

Tags: 12.04, installation, intel-graphics, intel

Will Ubuntu work on an **Intel 82845g MotherBoard** or are there any known incompabilities?
Would I need any special VGA drivers and were would I get them?

Comment: if you want to install it - then download and give it a try. Let us know the results.  Thanks.

Comment: I have installed Ubuntu on a 386DX system with 512 RAM, and it is working perfect...

Comment: A 386DX with the slots/DRAM type to handle 512MB? Do tell more...

Comment: Yes, it will work. No VGA driver is necessary, but the Unity (3D) environment won't work. Xubuntu or Lubuntu may be a better fit for your hardware.

Answer (score 2):

You can check hardware compatibilities from here in the future: http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/